# Notepad++: How to automatically set Language as Xml when load files

Tags: xml, text-editor, notepad++

Whenever I edit a .config file in Notepad++ (which is an XML file) I want the syntax highlighting to automatically color it like XML. How do I configure Notepad++ to do this so that I don't have to manually select it every time I open a .config file?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everybody! +1 to everybody, but I'm giving @Erikest the check b/c of the pretty pics.

Comment: (P.S. This is much easier in Sublime Text 2)

Comment: Same question three years before, with valid answer, in StackExchange / Superuser, just without screenshot: This (actually recent) [answer](https://superuser.com/a/58845) from [How to set the default language in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/q/58672).

Answer (score 204, accepted):

You can do this by using the Style Configurator (Settings Menu):

This image shows the php language, but it works for any language you want to map

[image]

Comment: Even though many have answered with the same answer, you get the +1 for the screenshot :)

Comment: I had to run Notepad++ as an administrator for this to work

Comment: Remember to select the language from the list to see the option to add User ext.

Comment: Make sure you have only added your user extension to one language. It was driving me crazy that adding .vue to HTML was not working... turns out long ago I had already added it to Javascript and that was overriding the HTML setting.

Answer (score 37):

From the `Settings` menu, choose `Style Configurator...`. Choose the XML Language from the list, and enter "config" in the `User ext` field.

Comment: +1, didn't realise you could do it there! I have always done it in the XML config files themselves.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think you can set a default style for all files (there may be some config file trickery that does allow it though) but as you specifically mention `.config` files, you can open the `langs.xml` or `langs.model.xml` file in your Notepad++ installation directory, find the `xml` section, and add `config` to the value of the `ext` attribute:

```
<Language name="xml" ext="xml xsml xsl xsd kml wsdl config" commentLine="" commentStart="&lt;!--" commentEnd="--&gt;">
</Language>
```

Or, use the Style Configuarator as noted by @AdamHawkes (+1), instead of messing around in the XML config files themselves!

Answer (score 13):

To set a 'global' default language:

1. Launch Notepad++
2. Click Settings > Preferences
3. Click on the New Document/Default Directory tab
4. Change the Default Language to HTML
5. Click the Close button

Answer (score 10):

For anyone that's seeing this >= 2017, the location has changed:
[image]

Comment: This must be selected answer, thanks a lot and voted up.

Comment: The accepted answer from 2012 still functions perfectly.

Comment: The accepted answer from 2012 shows the wrong location to find the settings; it has since moved (as the memo above the screenshot states).