# Set language automatically in Notepad++ according to file content, not file extension

Tags: xml, visual-studio, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

Please note that this question is different from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119517/notepad-how-to-automatically-set-language-as-xml-when-load-files).

I have files with extensions like .sln, .csproj, .config etc. These are all XML files. When I open them in notepad++, the language is set to XML and I can see syntax highlighting because I have followed the procedure explained in the above hyperlink. However I can have an XML file (a file that contains valid XML) with extension .kangaroo. I would like to know if there is way - such that when I open this file in Notepad++, it detects that yes it's an XML file and then automatically sets the language to XML. As a result the XML syntax highlighting will be there.

By the way Microsoft Visual Studio already has this functionality i.e. if a file named Temp.kangaroo contains valid XML and I open it in VS 2012 then it will do syntax highlighting. However Notepad++ doesn't do that by default. We need to manually follow the process explained in the hyperlink above.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want notepad++ to detect XML in files with arbitrary extensions?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - yes that is correct. Visual Studio does that exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In current N++, detection of language according to content of the file is not implemented. Language is detected only by file extension.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [release notes](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.8.4.html), it would appear that v6.8.4 (released on 16 Oct 2015) implemented the auto-detect language feature (at least for a subset of languages):

> 4. Apply new added language auto-detection (for php, xml, html and bash) in the case of unknown file extension.

Comment: it still doesn't detects web.config (which is a well-formed xml) as of January 2019!

Comment: Hi @Adaptabi - please make sure the web.config has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` as the first line - that should enable Notepad++ to recognise it as XML.