# How to set the Language of a .json file in Notepad++ automatically to JSON?

Tags: json, notepad++

When I open an XML file in Notepad++ I automatically get the '+' and '-' signs on the left side to collapse and expand XML elements. I'm not sure if that is done by the XML Tools plugin or not.

When I open a JSON file, I do not get these '+' and '-' signs. I first have to select Language -> JSON by hand.

Isn't there an option to associate the .json extension to the JSON Language in Notepad++, so I do not have to select the Language by hand all the time?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9119749/1770778) I read something about a Style Configurator, but I do not see a JSON Style in my list.

Or is it only possible by installing a plugin (JSTool or JSON Viewer)?

Comment: If you go to: `Settings` => `Preferences` => `File Association` (click this entry) ... is `web script` in the list to the right?  If so, that has `.json` listed, among MANY others.

Comment: @PaulT. Yes, it is in the list with Supported extensions. The list Registered extensions is empty.

Comment: Right, I show the same thing in the registed extension. The json extension is part of the `web script` group. When I open a json file, I get the folding ± sections as you mentioned. What Notepadd++ version do you have? I have v8.2.1

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have 7.7.1. So probably it is a bug and I just have to upgrade.